# How would I recreate a function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

While coding my own auto clicker I noticed an extreme inaccuracy with the click speed. When nothing I tried worked, I downloaded more auto clickers. I saw that every auto clicker I tested has extremely inaccurate CPS outputs, including mine. The inaccuracy seems to scale almost exponentially with the input CPS value.

I confirmed that my click speed tester works correctly by using different ones.
Here are my test results: (Bumps in the graph are due to inaccuracies)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDP5x.png

My question is: How would I calculate the "Input CPS" needed to reach the desired measurement?

Comment: Hi - welcome to MSE! I'm not sure that's exponential. There are many ways to model such a function. For very general purpose techniques the keyword is "interpolation". In this case you might be able to guess a function that fits well - if the autoclicker is naively implemented as something like `while (true) { click(); sleep(1/x) }`, then if there is some delay $d$ in the `click` function and unaccounted delay in the `sleep` function, the actual CPS will be $(d + x^{-1})^{-1}$. To find the best-fitting $d$ you can look to optimisation techniques. Eyeballing it, I reckon $d$ is about $0.0135$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

You are facing the typical problem of data regression.

Just looking at your data, it seems that simple hyperbolic models such as
$$y=x \,\frac{\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\,x^n}{1+\sum_{n=1}^p b_n\,x^n}$$ could be adequate.

Minimizing the sum of squares of absolute errors, for example, the simplest one $(p=1)$ would give (I made the coefficients rational)
$$a_0=\frac{3170}{3543} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_1=-\frac{25}{1801} $$ to which corresponds to $R^2=0.9988$ which is good.